# Write data to CSV file without adding empty rows between sets of data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My program writes data into a CSV file using the pandas' to_csv function. At first run, the CSV file is originally empty and my code wrote data in it (which is supposed to be). At the second run, (take note that I'm still using the same CSV file), my code wrote data in it again (which is good). The problem is, there is a large number of empty rows between the data from the first run and the data from the second run.

Below is my code:

```
#place into a file
csvFile = open(file, 'a', newline = '',encoding='utf-8')

if file_empty == True:
  df.to_csv(csvFile, sep=',', columns=COLS, index=False, mode='ab', encoding='utf-8') #header true
else:
  df.to_csv(csvFile, sep=',', columns=COLS, header=False, index=False, mode='ab', encoding='utf-8') #header false
```

I used the variable file_empty in order for the program to not write column headers if there is already data present in the CSV file.

Below is the sample output from the CSV file:

[Last data from first run is in line 396 of CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbl4J.png),
[first row data from second run is in line 1308 of the same CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H38H.png).

So there are empty rows starting from line 397 up to line 1307. How can I remove them so that when the program is run again, there is no empty rows between them?

Comment: Why are you using `mode='ab'` inside `to_csv`? Couldn't you just do `df.to_csv(file, columns=COLS, index=False, mode='a')` without using `csvFile` and with `mode='a'`?

Comment: Hello @Giorgio! Originally, it was at ```mode='a'``` but my data before has alternating empty rows. I searched for a solution and I found out that it was related to being it binary. Anyway, I removed it and changed it back to ```mode = 'a'```. Thanks for pointing that out.
But I still have a chunk of empty rows when the program is run again using the same CSV file

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything, but perhaps the problem is due to the fact that you are using `open` incorrectly: if you want to use `open` (but it's not needed, because `to_csv` already takes care of opening the file) you should also call `csvFile.close()` after each time you write something to it. The new rows added to the file are only visible after closing the file with `csvFile.close()`.

Comment: use append data option ,you can delete blank rows from a frame search for the solution

Comment: Hello @Giorgio, this is the guide I used for my program (that's why I used ```open```): https://www.dropbox.com/s/5enwrz2ggswns56/Telemedicine_twitter_v3.5.py?dl=0

I added  ```csvFile.close()``` after the ```to_csv``` but I still got the same results.

I tried removing the ```open(file)``` for the CSV but I still got the same results.

Comment: Hello @HietshKumar, I applied what you suggested by replacing the empty string values and deleting the rows. Thank you! Will close this thread now.

Comment: Hi @Giorgio, my problem is solved. I applied Hietsh Kumar 's suggestion. Thank you for pointing errors on my code. Will close this thread now.

Comment: @cerulean , good so just editing your quest and giving answering with solution code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the data sample and code to append the data and remove blank lines..[image]

## below are the lines may help you

```
import pandas
conso_frame = pandas.read_csv('consofile1.csv')
df_2 = pandas.read_csv('csvfile2.csv')

# Column Names should be same
conso_frame = conso_frame.append(df_2)
print(conso_frame)

conso_frame.dropna(subset = ["Intent"], inplace=True)
print(conso_frame)
conso_frame.to_csv('consofile1.csv', index=False)
```